# Loopback 4 hasMany with composite foreign key (postgres)

Tags: loopback4

To keep it simple I have a Customer 1 -- * Orders

```
Create table customers (
customer_id int,
offset_id int,
name text,
CONSTRAINT pk_customer_id PRIMARY KEY ( customer_id, offset_id )) 

Create table orders (
id int,
offset_id int,
name text,
customer_id int,
CONSTRAINT pk_order_id PRIMARY KEY ( id, offset_id ),
CONSTRAINT fk_orders_customerid FOREIGN KEY (customer_id, offset_id ) REFERENCES customer (customer_id, offset_id)
```

Is there any way to pull orders in to the customer model?

Answer (score 0):

See:

[How to create loopback 4 model, repository and controller without specifying an ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58590499/how-to-create-loopback-4-model-repository-and-controller-without-specifying-an/58594425#58594425)

To summarize: Loopback4 does not support composite keys out of the box according to their documentation.